# Passing a member of an int array to printf causes a Segmentation Fault in C

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

Here is the code I am using:

```
unsigned int* r;
// [snip]
r=(unsigned int *) malloc(filesize*sizeof(unsigned int));
for (pos=0;pos<max;pos++) {
  fread(&r, 1, 16, f);
  printf(
    "%x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x %x\t"\
    "%c %c %c %c %c %c %c %c %c %c %c %c %c %c %c %c\n",
    r[0], r[1], r[2], r[3], r[4], r[5], r[6], r[7], r[8], r[9], r[10], r[11], r[12], r[13], r[14], r[15],
    (char)r[0], (char)r[1], (char)r[2], (char)r[3], (char)r[4], (char)r[5], (char)r[6], (char)r[7], (char)r[8], (char)r[9], (char)r[10], (char)r[11], (char)r[12], (char)r[13], (char)r[14], (char)r[15]
  );
}

fclose(f);
```

Here is the gdb output:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x08048650 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff3c4) at binread.c:27
27          (char)r[0],(char)r[1],(char)r[2],(char)r[3],(char)r[4],(char)r[5],(char)r[6],(char)r[7],(char)r[8],(char)r[9],(char)r[10],(char)r[11],(char)r[12],(char)r[13],(char)r[14],(char)r[15]);
```

What is wrong with it?

Comment: What is the value of `filesize`?

Comment: Also, you are only reading 16 *bytes* and not 16 `int`.

Comment: I suggest you read about pointers so that you understand what the difference between a pointer and a pointed object is. And don't cast the return value of malloc.

Comment: @DavidBo There is a for loop, or do you mean the printf inside it?

Comment: I guess the pointer r point to an area less than 16*sizeof(unsigned int) bytes due to small filesize. Anymore, I guess your intension is to read 16 int instead of 16 bytes. you should write like this:
    fread(&r, sizeof(unsigned int), 16, f);

Comment: Anymore, you should release memory by free(r) in order to stop memory leak

Comment: @DarkHorse After dividing the code to lines and looking at gdb output I noticed it yields a Segmentation Fault when I fetch the value from the array for the second time.

Answer (score 2):

You give a pointer to a pointer to `fread`

```
fread(&r, 1, 16, f);
```

this should be

```
fread(r, sizeof(int), 16, f);
```

Comment: In the code `max` is size of file divided by 16. And if filesize%16!=0, max++.

Comment: I think there is no relation to loop because it faild at the first time.

Comment: @DarkHorse As of OP's comment, it fails at the second iteration. But since he gives a stack address to fread(), it might fail anytime, of course.